# Using ConfigParser as a report output

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to diff 2 reports to create a 3rd report. The report has sections with headers that I want to keep in place, but the info under that header I only want the lines that are different.

This is an example:

The first    Report1-

```
Filesystem Usage:
==============================
Use% Mounted
32% /lustre/work1
56% /lustre/work2

Inode Usage
==============================
IUse% Mounted
20% /lustre/work1
70% /lustre/work2
```

The second report 
    Report2-

```
Filesystem Usage:
==============================
Use% Mounted
34% /lustre/work1
56% /lustre/work2

Inode Usage
==============================
IUse% Mounted
20% /lustre/work1
71% /lustre/work2
```

Third report with only the diffs:

```
Filesystem Usage:
==============================
Use% Mounted
32% /lustre/work1
34% /lustre/work1

Inode Usage
==============================
IUse% Mounted
70% /lustre/work2
71% /lustre/work2
```

Would configParser be the right way to do this and how or is there a better tool I can use instead?

Comment: [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thank you for the suggestion. I have been working through the docs and it seems to get me close. I am trying to work on stripping the common entries away to only have the changed data, minus the headers. Could I ask for an example on this thread or should I open a new question?